# Some weird random ellipses in the Bounty Grace Period Started emails

Tags: feature-request, bounties, email, expired-bounty

I got this email a few days ago on my bounty entering the grace period:

[image: A screenshot of text: "Your bounty on the question … How to unlock “Classic Mode — Final Results” music? … ended and will be auto-closed after the 24-hour grace period expires."]

This looks pretty weird. The ellipsis at the beginning are strange, and the ellipsis at the end make it look like the whole title of the question doesn't have space to be displayed. I think these should be removed from the email template.